# Testing WSDL in Visual Studio

Tags: wcf, web-services, testing, wsdl, soapui

We have received a WSDL from our client that we use to communicate with their service.  I have made a service reference to it in our project, and had developed the code to interact with it.  I have used SoapUI to set up a mock service from their wsdl and have successfully tested my code.

My question is: is there a way to do WSDL testing only in visual studio?  I am new to SoapUI and some of my concerns are as follows:

- No validation of input - i dont think it really cares what I pass into it.  I would like to build more robust testing that would validate what i pass in and send...
- Dynamic reply messages. From what I understand, you can define a set of reply messages in SoapUI and one will be randomly selected.  I really need to be able to parse the input and send a reply specific to some of that data.  It wouldnt have to be fully developed but it would be a big step in actually emulating the client's service.

Is there a better way that I should be doing this testing?  Is there a Visual Studio tool I am unaware of?  Should I be trying to create my own testing service that serves the same endpoints as the client's service and implement custom code for testing?  Should I learn SoapUI better and possibly address some of my issues with it?

Please let me know, my coworker assumes that microsoft has a better way to test this kind of scenario.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to generate web service out of wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394930/how-to-generate-web-service-out-of-wsdl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create a dummy web service based on the wsdl to test this type of scenario.

For one way of how to do this see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395098

Comment: I will look into that option but is there no better way?  I am a little surprised microsoft doesnt have a tool like SoapUI.  It looks like the proxy that gets generated from svcutil can be configured to be a service instead of a client, but thats also some configuration work whereas soapui more or less "just works".