# Using a WSDL File instead of URL to WSDL in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a bit of a problem understanding how the WSDL local file is working. Normally when I need to consume a WSDL file I simply use SoapClient and pass the URL (Something like https://somesite.com/something?wsdl) to it and I am able to consume it. However, now with a new webservice provider they gave me 6 files. Two of which has .wsdl extensions and the rest has .xsd extensions. I have never consumed a web service like this before and I cannot find any tutorials online or any topics regarding this with PHP. I found one where they explained it in Visual Studio, but we need to get this working on PHP. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I did not even know this method existed as normally we consume them by URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally speaking, every wsdl is one web service, so there's 2 different services. Xsd files are just xml schema definition and you don't need it while you're calling web services. Use them to validate your soap xml.

If wsdl-s are v 1.1 you can try NuSoap on php site, if not, in Visual Studio you have wsdl.exe command line tool. Use that tool to simulate those web services localy, so you'll get excellent testing environment.

I also highly recommend you to try SoapUI.

Cheers,
Siniša

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The one wsdl file includes the other one it seems. I have loaded this in SOAPUI, but the connection cannot be made from there. These files are provided by a bank and as such the calls have to be made from our domain IP address since they only opened that IP for us. They are making this extremely hard.

Comment: So, if you have enough knowledge about .NET, use wsdl.exe tool to create web service simulation, you can more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394930/how-to-generate-web-service-out-of-wsdl