# Creating a .Net Web Service from WSDL in VS2019

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl, visual-studio-2019

For many years now I have been creating the WSDL for the web servers, implementing the web service in Axis2/C and consuming the services in C#.  There is a tool in Axis2/C to generate the stub code for both client and server, I have been using the server version to implement the service.  In the C# client projects, I follow the standard steps of adding a Service Reference for each of the web services.

It is now time to convert the Axis2/C Web services into C# Web Services.  Is there some process to generate the stub code of the C# service from the WSDL similar to the process of consuming a service reference?

Answer (score 1):

Under your project in Solution Explorer find "Connected Services". Double click and choose MS WCF Web Service Reference provider. Click on it and there you can browse to your WSDL file. 
Alternativelly if you are looking for some automation you can call wsdl.exe from command line to generate the stubs.

Comment: So I looked into this and from what I can tell the "connected Services" is about consuming a web service via WSDL that is implemented by other code.  While this is what most folks seem to want to do, it is the opposite of what I am trying to do...  It is my client that I don't want to change while I want to implement the server/backend in .Net.  Am I miss reading the documentation or something?  If so, what should I be looking for to learn how to use "Connected Services" to implement the WSDL?

Comment: Ah ok, now I got you. Never had to do something like this. May be this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406523/1105564